# Inner class does not allow maps

Tags: inner-class

I am working through a use case where I have a text field and a lookup field. I want to populate the lookup with the Id of the record that matches the name of the text field. After I query the lookup object records I think I need to have two maps, one string to Id and one Id to string so I can either get the Id or the name of the record depending on where I am.

I made an inner class that doesn't want to compile. I've used this same logic with lists before, however, even if I comment out everything and am left with this:

```
public without sharing class danclass 
{

    public class bunchOfMaps
    {
        public Map<String, Id> stringToId = new Map<String, Id>();
        pubilc Map<Id, String> idToString = new Map<Id, String>();
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Unexpected token 'Map'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is with the spellings of the access modifier for your second map in the inner class. Please change it to `public` from `pubilc` and it will resolve your issue.

I am successfully able to save the following code without any errors.

```
public without sharing class danclass 
{

    public class bunchOfMaps
    {
        public Map<String, Id> stringToId = new Map<String, Id>();
        public Map<Id, String> idToString = new Map<Id, String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: 2021 and still we get incorrect error messages like this. Instead of "Unknown/incorrect access modifier pubilc", we get the incomprehensible "Unexpected token 'Map'". Come on Salesforce, put some effort in this. We are building compilers for 70 years now, by now we should be getting more helpful error messages!